# Not able to view the value of the Radio Button

Tags: java, android

It doesn't show any error but when i run it on my phone the app crashes everytime!

`PizzaType.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pizzatype);
    RadioButton rButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioButton);
    String rText = rButton.getText().toString();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Pizzatype.this, Overview.class);
    intent.putExtra("Bbread","Brown Bread");
    startActivity(intent);
    String data = getIntent().getExtras().getString("Bbread");
}
```

Overview.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview);
    String value= getIntent().getStringExtra("Bbread");
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Pizzatype.class);
    intent.putExtra("Bbread", value);
    startActivity(intent);
    String data= getIntent().getStringExtra("Bbread");
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, what is the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: my app is like you can order pizza so you select your type of bread than your toppings so they involoe radio buttons and check boxes and at the end i have to show what the user seleted as a overview of the order like a receipt of what you got

Comment: And the stack trace?

Comment: there is really no stack trace invold

Comment: If it is crashing then there must be a stack trace otherwise it is not a crash.

Comment: is there a way to fix it? or can we do a stack dump

Comment: Run adb logcat and see what happens you should be able to see a stacktrace there.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning and re-running your project. Some times the R.java file get corrupted. and it leads to null pointer exceptions.